# Странности Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

Всем доброго времени суток!
При выводе карты на экран телефона, на ней появляются странные объекты:

[image: рис. 1. Открытие карты и добавление маркеров]

[image: рис. 2. Клик по маркеру]

Ранее я уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Тогда помогла перезагрузка устройства. Однако сейчас это не помогает. Пересоздание приложения и ключа так же не дают результата.
Да, еще, по сути выводятся иконки, используемые в приложении. Все иконки векторные.
Как вразумить карту?

Comment: Походу логика вашего приложения выводит "как-то" ваши же иконки на карту. Уберите всю логику и выведите пустую карту без объектов.

Comment: Пробовал. Получим первый рисунок, только без маркеров. Вообще обведенная иконка на первом рисунке выводится еще до полной отрисовки карты.